# Fullcalendar updateEvent doesn't rerender

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to add events to my DB via fullcalendar. So I want to add an event and set its id to the id it gets in my DB.

```js
function addCalEvent(event) {
  var jEvent = {};
  jEvent['startTime'] = moment(event.start).unix();
 jEvent['worker']="GUZ"
 jEvent['title']=event.title;
  if (event.end) {
    jEvent['endTime'] = moment(event.end).unix();
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: 'dux.html',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      type: 'addNewEvents',
      event: jEvent,
   REQUEST_TOKEN: "REQUEST_TOKEN>",
    },
    datatype: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    event.id=data;
   event.title="NEW";
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
  },
});
}
```

The ajax retrieves the id of the added event and the id and title do get changed, but the 'updateEvent' method doesn't seem to be called, because there is no change to the rendered events title or id.

Comment: How are you adding your the new events to the calendar?

Comment: i call 'renderEvent' in the 'dayClick' function and call addCalEvent after.

Comment: `event.id=data` this is really the problem I think. Once you change the ID, fullCalendar cannot match it to the existing event (because if you don't supply an event ID when you first created the event, fullCalendar assigns one automatically for you). But your logic is back to front...what you should do is first send the event data to your server, and get back the ID. Only then, when you know the server has accepted the event and successfully saved it, should you create the event in fullCalendar using renderEvent. And then you don't need updateEvent at all.

Comment: @ADyson I agree with ADyson on this one. According to the docs, you can't update an event that you've created yourself, it has to be an event coming from the calendar e.g. the event returned on `eventClick`. So I think the best course of action is what ADyson suggested, send the `ajax` request to get the event id from your db in the `dayClick` event and then using that id, create your event and then call `renderEvent`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
apperently if you make a asynchronous ajax call the order in which commands are executed isn't the order you write it.
I need to add async: false to make this work.

Answer (score -1):

You can manually call rerender events with `$('#calendar').fullCalendar( ‘rerenderEvents’ )`

Link to docs [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rerenderEvents)

Comment: But i dont want to rerender all Events. Thats why i wanted to use the 'updateEvent' Method.

Comment: Could you possibly add a jsfiddle of your issue?